# Cookie in rest-client Ruby

Tags: ruby, rest-client

Is it possible to add cookie like

```
key[index]=value
```

Here is my code

```
options[:headers][:cookies] = {:cookie_key => 'cookie_value'}
resource[options[:path]].get(options[:headers])
```

This code works fine but when I try something like

```
options[:headers][:cookies] = {:cookie_key => {} }
```

I get `/../../util.rb:16:in 'unescape': undefined method 'tr' for #<Hash:0x0000000195f7d0> (NoMethodError)`

Comment: as far as i can understand error you've got not really related to question you asked ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cookies basically can only [store](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Cookies.html) strings (for each first-level key).

In order to store hash in cookies values, you need serialize/deserialize the data, for example, [with JSON](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Serializers/JSON.html)

```
cookies[:i_need_to_store_hash] = hsh.to_json
```

and than

```
i_need_to_get_my_hash_back = JSON.parse(cookies[:i_need_to_store_hash])
```

but remember that cookies very limited in size (4096 bytes)